# Lenovo Legion 5 - Loud beep error sound

Tags: linux, audio, lenovo-laptop

In many cli programs when I press a shortcut, that doesn't exists (in nano for example), also in Firefox when I search for a word that doesn't exist or when I shut the computer down (everything: hardware button, terminal, desktop environment) I hear a load beep.

Here's a recording: http://www.sndup.net/tfdk

The sound is independant of my volume settings and appears in all desktop environments, also in tty and on every Linux distro I tried.

My Hardware: Legion 5 Pro-16ACH6H

Does anyone know how to turn it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The laptop has a "[PC speaker](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PC_speaker)" (also called "beeper").

To disable it unload the kernel module `pcspkr` by running `modprobe -r pcspkr`.

To prevent the module from being loaded on boot, blacklist it:
Create a new file: `/etc/modprobe.d/nobeep.conf` (you can freely choose the file name)
with the line: `blacklist pcspkr`